# Force specific line to render for test?

Tags: google-dfp

**Short version**

Is there a way to force a specific banner to show so I can take a screenshot? I know I can Photoshop it etc, but that's not really nice.

**The whole thing**

In name of an intermediary firm I regularly place banners for their clients on my site via DFP (my account). They always request a screenshot of the site displaying the clients' banner to pass on to them showing that I've started the campaign.

Unfortunately sometimes the frequency is so low that even "As fast as possible" takes a ton of pageviews before the banner shows up (which is also not really nice towards the other advertisers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check documentation for [Preview a creative](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177231?hl=en)

**In short:**

You need to open creative, click *Preview* tab, click *on site* and put url of the page on your site where you expect to see your creative

[image: generate preview link]

**Update**

Looks like problem related to way you are opening creative. I have reproduced this behaviour.

- If you open creative directly trough search it shows no **On site** link
  [image: no preview link]
- If you open line item first and from this screen navigate to very same creative, you will see **On site** link
  [image: with preview link]

Comment: If it was that easy I would've found it myself, that page only has "New window" in my DFP, which I already tried before posting here. It's just a blank window with the creative.

Comment: What type of creative did you use? There [several of them](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3163574)

Comment: I have several image typed creatives and a 3rd party one. It's not visible for any of them.

Comment: Could you add screen shot of preview page in dfp? Normally it looks like [this](http://adopsaudit.com/using-dfp-preview-creative-to-create-a-test-page/)

Comment: My dfp looks exactly like in the screenshots except I don't have "On site". Just have "New window  Mobile"

Comment: Looking at it like that it makes perfect sense. A single creative can be linked to multiple item lines so it wouldn't know which line item to update. 
Good catch and I thank you for your effort and patience.